# Physiological Effect of Mannitol

Tags: physiology, pharmacology, blood-pressure

Which Starling Force is affected by Mannitol?

I am either thinking hydrostatic pressure of interstitial fluid (because it increases interstitial fluid volume) or hydrostatic pressure of capillary (because it is also increased plasma volume). I read that it deals with osmotic pressure but was unsure as it is a crystalloid and not a colloid.